# Python: Parse text table and convert into nested data structure

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to parse a text table which has the following format:

```
-----------------------------------------
| Serial |     Name             | marks |
| Number |First | Middle | Last |       |
-----------------------------------------
| 1      | john |   s    |  doe |  56   |
| 2      | jim  |   d    |  bill|  60   |
```

After parsing the table, the output should be a nested dictionary with the data as lists.

```
TableData = {'Serial Number':[1,2], 
             'Name': {'First':[john, jim]} 
                     {'Middle':[s, d]} 
                     {'Last':[doe, bill]}
             'marks': [56, 60]
            }
```

As of now I have logic to get the positions of the delimiters (|), and I can extract the text in between the delimiters.

```
posList = [[0,9,32,40],[0,9,16,25,32]]
nameList = [['Serial','Name','marks'],['Number ','First','Middle','Last','  ']]
```

But I am having difficulty converting this to the nested dictionary structure.

Comment: Where are you stuck? The next step here seems to be comparing the two lists inside `posList` and distinguishing two cases: either the column in the second line has the same extent as in the line above (e.g. "Serial Number" between 0 and 9), or the column is divided (e.g. "Name" goes from 9 to 32, but then you have "sub-columns" 9-16, 16-25 and 25-32).

Comment: I was stuck at how to make the data structure (row-wise or column-wise). Bill's solution looks good, so I accepted this answer for now. But I was wondering if there was a different approach I could try like building a tree like structure that could parse any number of subcolumns with any level of subcolumns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know what the data structure should look like, then can't you forget about the first 3 rows and extract data from the rest of the rows? For example, assuming the table is located in a text file `table_file`, then

```
table_data = {'Serial Number':[],
              'Name':{'First': [],
                      'Middle': []
                      'Last': []},
              'Marks': []}

with open(table_file, 'r') as table:
    # skip first 3 rows
    for _ in range(3):
        table.next()

    for row in table:
        row = row.strip('\n').split('|')
        values = [r.strip() for r in row if r != '']
        assert len(values) == 5
        table_data['Serial Number'].append(int(values[0]))
        table_data['Name']['First'].append(values[1])
        table_data['Name']['Middle'].append(values[2])
        table_data['Name']['Last'].append(values[3])
        table_data['Marks'].append(values[4])
```

**EDIT:**
To construct the table_data dictionary, consider the following pseudocode. Fair warning, I tested this and it seems to work for your example and should work for anything with two rows of header. However, it is sloppy because I wrote in about 10 minutes. However, it could be an OK start from which you can improve and expand. This also assumes you have code for extracting `pos_list` and `name_list`.

```
for itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

def create_table_dict(pos_list, name_list):
    intervals = []
    for sub_list in pos_list:
        intervals.append(list(pairwise(sub_list)))

    items = []
    for interval, name in zip(intervals, name_list):
        items.append([ (i, n) for i, n in zip(interval, name) ])

    names = []
    for int1, name1 in items[0]:
        past_names = []
            for int2, name2 in items[1]:
        if int1[0] == int2[0]:
            if int1[1] == int2[1]:
                names.append(' '.join((name1, name2)).strip())
        elif int2[1] < int1[1]:
                past_names.append(name2)
        elif int1[0] < int2[0]:
            if int2[1] < int1[1]:
            past_names.append(name2)
            elif int1[1] == int2[1]:
            names.append('{0}:{1}'.format(name1, 
                                          ','.join(past_names + [name2])))

    table = {}
    for name in names:
        if ':' not in name:
            table[name] = []
        else:
            upper, nested = name.split(':')
            nested = nested.split(',')
            table[upper] = {}
            for n in nested:
                table[upper][n] = []

    print table
```

Comment: The table parser is supposed to parse any arbitrary table with any heading that follows the table format that i posted. So we need to make the data structure as we parse the table.

Comment: I edited the post to include some somewhat sloppy code to create the table format as well.